# Grabbing Just The Top Entry From A LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I basically have a lot of poorly designed code to do something that, I'm sure, can be done far more elegantly.

What I'm trying to do is grab the last date from a database table.

```
var Result = 
from a in DB.Table
orderby a.Date descending
select new {Date = a};

foreach(var Row in Result)
{
LastDate = Row.Date.Date;
break;
}
```

Basically, there's a foreach loop that is designed to run only once.  Crappy code!  What's a "best practice" way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var first = Result.First();
```

If the result set is empty, this will throw an exception; you can use FirstOrDefault() which will return a null if the result set is empty.

Answer (score 8):

Call `First()`.
For example:

```
LastDate = 
    (from a in DB.Table
     orderby a.Date descending
     select a.Date
    ).First();
```

If the table might be empty, call `FirstOrDefault()`, which will return `DateTime.MinValue` instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3):

```
var LastDate = DB.Table.OrderBy(a => a.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

FirstOrDefault() and as a bonus, you can use LastOrDefault() for... you guessed it...

**[edit]** -- oh, sudden rush there with the same answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you could also call `Result.Take(1)`
The difference between `Take(1)` and `First()` is that First returns a single object, and Take returns an IEnumerable of the type.

Comment: He doesn't want an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

If Date is a reference type then you may consider the coalesce operator.

var LastDate = Result.FirstOrDefault() ?? new Date();

Comment: Only if you first write `.Cast<DateTime?>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find the latest date, you could use the "Max" function (which I believe linq2sql will convert to a SQL MAX operation):

```
var maxdate = DB.Table.Max(a => a.Date)
```